# Using the splat operator in Parallel assignment in Ruby more than once on one side

Tags: ruby

I've recently encountered this example of the splat operator:

```
first, *, last = 1, 2, *[3,4,5]
```

and it worked.

so I was wondering, can you use the splat operator more than once on either the left or the right side? I get unexpected star error each time I do that, but was just wondering for the heck of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have more than one splat on the left side. (At least not on the same level of nesting.) After all, it means "gobble up all values", so what would two splats even *mean*? It just doesn't make sense.

Note: something like this is of course possible:

```
a, *b, (c, *d) = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

The two splats are on different levels of nesting, they don't interfere with each other.

And on the right hand side, there's no problem either:

```
a = 1, 2, *[3, 4], *[5, 6]
```

It just means *expansion*, and there's no problem expanding multiple arrays on the right hand side.

Comment: *something like this* I'm not sure how ruby calls it, but in other languages it's called "pattern matching". I wrote something about it(and put link) in my answer.

Comment: @DarekNędza: Ruby calls it *parallel assignment*, it's a form of *destructuring bind*. Pattern Matching is a *much more* powerful concept than just simple destructuring bind.

Comment: What does *bind* means?

Answer (score 0):

On the one side(left or right) you can use splat(`*`) **only** once.
`first, *, last` -> here, one `*`
1, 2, *[3,4,5] -> here, it's the same

However(!) you can use splat operators more than once if you use *pattern matching*(not sure if ruby calls it that way though but in other language similar feature is called that way, so I will use this term):

```
 a, *b, (*c, d) = 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
#=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
 a
#=> 1
 b
# => [2, 4, 5, 6]
 c
# => [7, 8, 9, 10]
 d
# 11
```

As you can see I used splat operator with b and c variable. Parenthesis in this case is the pattern matching mentioned earlier.
[Here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) you can read a little about this.

To sum up without *pattern matching*(`()`) you can use it once.
With *pattern matching*, you can use it once **per** `()`(pattern matching)

ps. `*` in `*[1,2,3]` is not used as assignment so you can use it few times:

```
a = *[1,2,3], *[4,5,6]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: What languages call it pattern matching?